# JavaScript - conversion of "0" to number

Tags: javascript

I can understand why

`10 % "test"`

returns `NaN`... because "test" is converted to a number first which gives `NaN` and then any subsequent arithmetic operation involving `NaN` results in `NaN` too.

But why does

```
    10 % "0"
```

return `NaN` ?

`"0"` is usually converted to a number as `0` e.g. in `1 * "0"`.

If I try `10 / "0"` this gives `Infinity` which also makes sense.

So... why does that expression `10 % "0"` return `NaN` ?! Any logic behind this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516251/why-is-n-mod-0-undefined

Comment: @Taki I know math, but JavaScript is not pure math :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is right, in all the *number only* operators, if used in strings, Javascript will try to convert them in numbers.

The same also happens with the remainder operator:

```js
const x = "10"%"3";
console.log('10 % 3 = ' + x);
```

So why you get `NaN` evaluating `10%"0"`? Well, it will be converted to `10%0`, but the remainder operator has no particualr meaning if used on 0 (you can't divide by 0 in first instance). So you get NaN:

```js
const x = 10 % 0; // numeric only operation
console.log('10 % 0 = ' + x); // NaN, the above operation has no meaning
```

Answer (score 2):

`10 % 0` also returns `NaN` because you're asking what's the remainder when you divide by 0, and there's no meaningful answer to that.